# Reactstrap Carousel has extra captions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, reactstrap

I'm using the built-in Carousel component from reactstrap (version 9.0.1) and reactJS (version 18.2.0), and it works perfectly fine except for if I add a caption into any one of the slides, that caption ends up showing at the bottom left of the component on all of the slides, like in the screenshot below.[image: screenshot of issue]

Here's the code I have (I pretty much copy and pasted the example code in the [reactstrap documentation](https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-carousel--carousel))

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Carousel,
  CarouselItem,
  CarouselControl,
  CarouselIndicators,
  CarouselCaption,
} from 'reactstrap';
import avengers from '../../app/assets/img/avengers.jpg';
import justiceLeague from '../../app/assets/img/justice-league.jpg';
import spawn from '../../app/assets/img/spawn.jpg';
import strayDogs from '../../app/assets/img/stray-dogs.jpg';

const comics = [
  {
    src: avengers,
    altText: 'Avengers #1 Cover',
    caption: 'Avengers #1',
    key: 0,
  },
  {
    src: justiceLeague,
    altText: 'Justice League Infinity #1 Cover',
    // caption: 'Justice League Infinity #1',
    key: 1,
  },
  {
    src: spawn,
    altText: 'Spawn #1 Cover',
    // caption: 'Spawn #1',
    key: 2,
  },
  {
    src: strayDogs,
    altText: 'Stray Dogs #1 Cover',
    // caption: 'Stray Dogs #1',
    key: 3,
  },
];

const ComicBookCarousel = (args) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const [animating, setAnimating] = useState(false);

  const next = () => {
    if (animating) return;
    const nextIndex = activeIndex === comics.length - 1 ? 0 : activeIndex + 1;
    setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
  };

  const previous = () => {
    if (animating) return;
    const nextIndex = activeIndex === 0 ? comics.length - 1 : activeIndex - 1;
    setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
  };

  const goToIndex = (newIndex) => {
    if (animating) return;
    setActiveIndex(newIndex);
  };

  const slides = comics.map((item) => {
    return (
      <CarouselItem
        onExiting={() => setAnimating(true)}
        onExited={() => setAnimating(false)}
        key={item.src}
      >
        <img src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
        <CarouselCaption
          captionText={item.caption}
          captionHeader={item.caption}
        />
      </CarouselItem>
    );
  });

  return (
    <Carousel
      activeIndex={activeIndex}
      next={next}
      previous={previous}
      {...args}
    >
      <CarouselIndicators
        items={comics}
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        onClickHandler={goToIndex}
      />
      {slides}
      <CarouselControl
        direction='prev'
        directionText='Previous'
        onClickHandler={previous}
      />
      <CarouselControl
        direction='next'
        directionText='Next'
        onClickHandler={next}
      />
    </Carousel>
  );
};

export default ComicBookCarousel;
```

Comment: The code works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-tree-xo4st5?file=/src/App.js. I guess there is some problem with css.

Comment: Better this way `<CarouselItem key={item.key} />`

Comment: digging around in the developer tools to see what html is being displayed, it seems that the carousel indicators (which show up as <button> tags) are getting assigned a label to them, which is the caption that I want displayed with the image.